# SQL: string PK ( maybe composite ) or auto_number artificial PK with unique constraint?

Tags: sql, primary-key

I am creating a new database and have a dilemma: I have an authors table. My requirements are that it should contain the firstName and lastName columns and I shouldn't allow two authors that have the same firstName and lastName.

My first ideea was to make firstName and lastName composite pk, and that's it!

But, I will tie this table to other tables so, to make my life easier I though of using an int auto_increment PK and make a composite UC of firstName and lasteName.

My question is generally: let's say I have a persons table and I can use the SSN as PK. If i tie this table to n tables duplicating the SSN value in the child tables may consume more memory than rather using an int auto_increment PK and making UC of  SSN column?

What approach is better, and when to use what?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to keep your PRIMARY KEY separated from the rest of the table, the business logic. Plus it is way faster to have a separate PK because of indexing, it is so much better for performance, easier to maintain and to link tables to each other, it also ensures faster execution of statements on the table.

Your best bet would be to go for a PK column like `id` then have a separate `UNIQUE` constraint for the firstName-lastName.

Comment: But in the SSN example? I mean when I only have a single comlumn, I can go with making SSN the PK right?

Comment: If this is the case, even if the SSN is unique and can't have duplicates, it is still better to have a separate ID column. I know, thats what they taught me in school, to use a unique column like SSN as PK, but it isn't good for performance.